# Getting all objects referenced in a foreign key field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have models similar to

```
class Person(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=100)

class Movie(Model):
    ...
    director = ForeignKey(Person)
```

How would I get the set of all Person objects which are set as the director for any Movie object?

edit: to clarify, if my Movie 'table' consisted of two entries, one with director A and one with director B, and my Person 'table' consisted of the three entries A, B, and C, I would want to get the set {A, B}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out,

```
Person.objects.exclude(director__set=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need get the person:

my_person = Person.objects.get(name="XXX")

Then, get all his movies:

person.movie_set.all()