# Reverse foreign key in filter of QuerySet in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Let's say I have two models:

```
class Human(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(#...

class Jacket(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Human, #...
```

So, thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306897/django-reverse-lookup-of-foreign-keys) I was able to figure out that I could get all Jackets of a Human by doing: `human_object.jacket_set`

Now I want to get a Queryset with all Humans that own a jacket.
Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442882/getting-all-objects-referenced-in-a-foreign-key-field), I tried something like this,

```
Human.objects.exclude(jacket__set=None)
```

but I wouldn't be here if that had worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can obtain the queryset of `Human`s that own (at least) one `Jacket` with:

```
Human.objects.filter(jacket__isnull=False).distinct()
```

This works because we make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the `Jacket` model, and we filter out the ones without a related `Jacket` with `jacket__isnull=False`. By using `.distinct()` we prevent that the same `Human` is returned multiple times (once *per* related `Jacket`).

In the query it uses the `related_name_query` to reference the related object, which is by default the name of the model in lowercase. In case a `related_name` is specified, it will use the `related_name`.